# Claiming honours in rubber bridge

Tags: bridge

When playing rubber bridge, can the declarer still claim after the hand is over but the next hand has not been dealt?

Answer (score 2):

From the [2014 Laws of Rubber Bridge](http://www.acbl.org/acbl-content/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf):

> **Law 76 - Responsibility for the Score**
>
> ....  Honors may be claimed until the next hand has been dealt, or the
> rubber has been completed and scored - whichever comes sooner.

and

> **Law 78 Correction of the Score**
>
> When it is acknowledged by a majority of the players that a scoring error was made in recording an
> agreed upon result (e.g. failure to enter honors or incorrect
> computation of score), the error must be corrected if discovered
> before the net score for the rubber has been agreed to. However,
> except with the consent of all four players, an erroneous agreement as
> to the number of tricks won by each side may not be corrected after
> all players have called on the next deal.
>
> In case of disagreement
> between two scores kept, the recollection of the majority of the
> players as to the facts governs.